# How to remove multiple row from datagridview without using index?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to remove multiple row from datagridview,
I tried the below code, here row's are getting deleted based on index.

```
for (int m = 0; m < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; m++)
        {
            if (dataGridView3.Rows[m].Cells[2].Value != null)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; n++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value != null)
                    {

                        if (dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value.Equals(dataGridView3.Rows[m].Cells[2].Value) &&
                            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value.Equals(dataGridView3.Rows[m].Cells[8].Value))
                        {
                            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(n);
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

here rows are not getting deleted properly, because index is changed after every single delete, so some records are missing out from loop.

can anyone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to remove items from the collection as you iterate through it like this, you'll need to work backwards through the collection of rows:

```
// start with the last row, and work towards the first
for (int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
{
    if (dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value != null)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value.Equals(dataGridView3.Rows[m].Cells[2].Value) &&
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value.Equals(dataGridView3.Rows[m].Cells[8].Value))
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(n);
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use LINQ to find your matches first, and *then* remove them:

```
var rowToMatch = dataGridView3.Rows[m];

var matches =
    dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value.Equals(rowToMatch.Cells[2].Value)
                               && row.Cells[8].Value.Equals(rowToMatch.Cells[8].Value))
                 .ToList();

foreach (var match in matches)
    dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(match);
```

Just to make it less of a maintenance head-ache, you might want to use the column name instead of the column index too... just a thought.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Winney :-) it work's perfectly :-)